# Bluetooth headset the other party can't hear me on any internet calls

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I have iPhone 4S, I bought new bluetooth headset, it is working fine on normal calls, but when using it on internet calls like WhatsApp calls or Messenger calls etc… the other party can’t hear me but I hear him very well, and the Audio button is flickering between (Audio symbol with 3 brackets) and (Audio symbol with bluetooth logo) I have attached gif image showing the flickering.

[image]

By the way, I bought another one, it worked for the first time but after charging it it makes the same problem.

Comment: The iPhone 4s is in “vintage“ support status. The maximum supported iOS version is 9.3.6.  Check your settings to make sure the apps you are using have permission to use the microphone. Once you have the headset and microphone paired, restart your phone. Does it work better after that?

Comment: Don't remember if older ios versions have 'Bluetooth Permission' feature, but if it does, enable that too.

Comment: It is working with normal call, the problem with any internet calls like WhatsApp or Messenger etc..., I already gave permission to WhatsApp but still other party can't hear me, I can hear them very well